# Angular Material and Bootstrap? BS CSS interrupt the styling of NG Material?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, angular, angular-material, single-page-application

I am developing an Angular2 SPA app. In the beginning, I was using Angular, Bootstrap 4 CSS and Angular Bootstrap, however, gradually I am moving to using Angular Material. Basically all these frameworks and component suites live well, however, I find that with the existence of Bootstrap 3/4, the alignment of HTML elements (buttons, inputs and checkboxs) in a row look no good. If I remove Bootstrap, they are aligned horizontally and perfectly. Because I am still using some Angular Bootstrap components, I can't get rid of Bootstrap which provide a lot good stuffs not yet covered by NG Material and fxFlex.

Questions:

1. Is it good or recommended to have Angular Material and Bootstrap together?
2. Is it good to use an application level stylesheet with a small portion of Bootstrap CSS only?

Comment: there is no harm in having bootstrap and material together

Comment: As I mentioned, the horizontal alignments are not looking good in some combinations of HTML elements. Overall usable, but the pixel accuracy are looking odd.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using `Angular` just make use of `Angular Material` as it also come up with styled components which works right of the bat.

Though at the same time in my `ng2` projects I also use `bootstrap` though  not everything in bootstrap, I just took a portion of it like `bootstrap-modal`, `bootstrap-tooltip` etc. they work pretty well as long as you don't put the entire `style.min.css` of bootstrap.